# jQuery | Is calling setTimeout on mousemove bad practice/inefficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code determines if the user is online :

```
/* User online status */
    var online = true;
    var activeTimeout = setTimeout(_setUserInactive, 5000);

    $(document).on("mousemove keydown keyup click", function () {
        clearTimeout(activeTimeout);
        activeTimeout = setTimeout(_setUserInactive, 5000);

        if (!online) {
            _setUserActive();
        }
    });
```

Pretty simple. But, is this going to cause performance issues? It will call every time the mouse is moved. Thanks.

Comment: Far from the question but you can delegate this task to a library if you haven't checked this one yet. It suits what you want, to check if the user is still active or idle. https://github.com/serkanyersen/ifvisible.js

Comment: Most browsers have a profiler available -- for this or any other performance question like this, it's a good practice to test it out yourself, too.

Comment: @Scovetta This is a different question, but I can't post for another hour, so it would be nice I could get some help. How can I set the user inactive when he/she leaves my website?

Comment: I use a websocket and poll for response.  I think just about any variety of timer is by nature inefficient.